# luajit qsort callback example memory leak

Tags: callback, lua, ffi, qsort, luajit

I have the following `qsort` example to try out callbacks in luajit. However it has a memory leak (`luajit: not enough memory` when executing) which is not obvious to me.

Can somebody give me some hints on how to create a proper callback example?

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

-- ===============================================================================

ffi.cdef[[
    void qsort(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
]]


function compare(a, b)
    return a[0] - b[0] 
end

-- ===============================================================================

-- Explicitly convert to a callback via cast
local callback = ffi.cast("int (*)(const char *, const char *)", compare)

local data     = "efghabcd"
local size     = 8 
local loopSize = 1000 * 1000 * 100.

local bytes    = ffi.new("char[15]")

-- ===============================================================================

for i=1,loopSize do 
    ffi.copy(bytes, data, size)
    ffi.C.qsort(bytes, size, 1, callback)
end
```

Platform: OSX 10.8
luajit: 2.0.1

Comment: updated the description to be more specific and fixed a wrong var name in the code.

Comment: you can work around it by placing a `collectgarbage()` call in the loop

Comment: Adding info for other people - Mike just fixed this - http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/Beginners-FFI-callback-memory-leak,2

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that lua never gets a chance to perform a full garbage collection cycle inside the tight loop. As hinted by the comment, you can correct this by calling `collectgarbage()` yourself inside the loop.

Note that calling `collectgarbage()` on every iteration will impact the running time of whatever you're benching. To minimize this, you should set a threshold to limit how often `collectgarbage()` gets called:

```
local memthreshold = 2 ^ 20 / 1024
local start = os.clock()
for i = 1, loopSize do
    ffi.copy(bytes, data, size)
    ffi.C.qsort(bytes, size, 1, callback)
    if collectgarbage'count' > memthreshold then
      collectgarbage()
    end
end
local elapse = os.clock() - start
print("elapsed:", elapse..'s')
```

Comment: In this case, using `collectgarbage()` solves the symptoms. As described in the comments above, this was a bug.

Comment: @dh82 It looks like the latest LuaJIT-2.0.2 download still suffers from this bug. I just built it with mingw and retested your example script. It still errors out with not enough mem.

Comment: @greatwolf correct, LuaJIT-2.0.2 was released on 2013-06-03 and the bug was fixed on 2013-06-20 (17 days after) it appears on the mailing list. So if you're hitting this issue, just compile from git HEAD, which is recommended by Mike Pall if you can, btw. It seems that in his workflow, git head always contains stable versions with the latest fixes, even if they are unreleased.